# Yii2 , Rbac, как правильно вывести имя роли d GridVIew

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

Я вывожу таблицу, и вывожу в ней также роль пользователя

мой grid widget

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'username',
            'email:email',
            'status',
            'created_at',
            [
                'attribute' => 'roles',
                'value' => function ($user){
                    if(!empty($userRole = $user->getRoles()[0])){
                        return $userRole;
                    }
                }
            ],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

функция getRoles

```
public function getRoles(){
        $roles = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($this->getId());
        return ArrayHelper::getColumn($roles, 'name', false);
    }
```

Роль выводиться, но есть проблема. количество запросов в базу данных, зависит от количества пользователей выведенных в таблицу на странице пагинации(к примеру если в таблице выводиться 30 пользователей то соотвецтвенно будет 30 запросов в БД, чтобы получить имя роли). Как можно улучшить это и сократить количество запросов в базу данных?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону hasMany класса таблицы с пользователями и ролями

Comment: когда пользователь авторизуется, можно кэшировать его роли.

Comment: fedornabilkin, в таблицу я вывожу всех пользователей зарегистрированных на моём сайте.

Comment: Евгений,я пытаюсь получить через hasMany, return $this->hasMany(Role::className(), ['id' => 'role']); но получаю ошибку Call to undefined method yii\rbac\Role::find()